# How to use a jpg as a background image in html

Tags: html, css, jpeg

I'm trying to use a jpeg that I have saved into a file as a background to a html file using its file path as the url. I have the following but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image:url('C:\Users\...\background.jpg');    
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center; 
    }
```

Comment: If you're just opening the page locally in your browser (versus running on a web server), try the `file://` protocol in your url

Comment: I need undestand the relative path.
```https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, So giving relative path is very easy, only you need to understand the basic folder structure of your project, although I am not sure how you are keeping your files and folder structure so I will tell the ideal folder structure for front-end project (according to me), and will explain to you how you can use a relative path for assets,

let's keep the main HTML file in a folder named by your project, For example `Peadar08` is the project name. so put an index.html file in your folder, and on the same level keep a folder for your assets, like this...

[image]

then in **ASSETS** folder create more folders for your respective assets(images, js, css etc), like this...

[image]

Now just see an example for images, and you can follow the same for other assets,
So you can use images in 2 ways,

1. As an **IMAGE** by `img` tag in your HTML, so keeping in mind the above stuture you can use images in your HTML like this.

   `<img src="assets/images/example.png" alt="altText"/>`

So your image will render perfectly as assets and your HTML file is on the same level so just mention the path starting with the folder name.

now see another example if you need to use your image as a background image by CSS

so all you need to do is use of `../` to go one folder back, just because you are in css file and `../` this will take you one folder up, I.e in assets folder and then you can foloow the path. so in your CSS use this..

```
.ExampleClass {
    background-image: url('../assets/images/example.png');
}
```

to move 2 folder up just use `../../` and so on.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. While it didn't work, I appreciate your advice on the file structure. I think my issue could be how I call it? Where would you recommend to get the full code? Tks

Comment: I didn't get your last line. You want me to see your code for error or mistake?

Comment: Any online resources, I've tried w3school.com but their examples don't work. Thanks

Comment: I have created this for you, you can have a look, images as background and as IMG both are there. https://drive.google.com/open?id=18bE6P44S8TObwlCu-fVJczBsClHXDapc

Comment: Atul, Thank you! Really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: if this helped you, don't forget to mark it as right answer.

Comment: Tks. I'm still new to this!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify location directly from the C:, but from the root directory in relation to where your index.html is.

Answer (score 1):

You could just copy the link directly from where you found the image by right clicking the image in the browser and selecting 'Copy Image Address' and paste that in the image URL.